# Why is my `flex` table row not centered in Edge?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For a website that I am developing I have a table. The table consists of x rows. When a second row has less items than the first one, I want to center the items horizontally. For this I use flexbox. In Chrome and Firefox this works fine. But when I test it in Edge, the table row items are not centered.

> Table row

```
<tr>
    <td >
        <div class="table-image item-image"></div>
        <div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Diensten</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="table-image item-image"></div>
        <div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Domotica</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="table-image item-image"></div>
        <div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Communicatie</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="table-image item-image"></div>
        <div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Personalisatie</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The table row itself has the following styling:

> Styling.css

```
tr {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

td {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Chrome/Firefox behaviour:

[][][][] Row 1

-[][][]- Row 2 (centered)

Edge behaviour:

[][][][] Row 1

[][][]-- Row 2 (not centered)

Does anyone know why Edge cannot handle this and how to fix it?

Comment: did you tried adding to `td` the property `min-width: 0;`

Comment: Not yet, but I just tried it and it does not help

Comment: one way could be go to https://autoprefixer.github.io/ ,paste you css code into the prefixer and copy it into your projekt

Comment: Unfortunatelly when I try that, it doesn't make any difference. Thanks for the url though!